# Read a directory structure in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to read a directory in my resource folder of my iPhone app.

```
NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"Capitalization"  ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"MyDirectory"];
NSLog(@"Path : %@",path);
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
if(fileExists){
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                                            error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"Data from plist %@",content);
}else {
    NSLog(@"File Not Found");
    //exit(1);  // if file not found exit the application.
}
```

But everytime I am getting NULL.
please help. My Directory can contain another directory also, in that case i have to get the directory name also.

Comment: Have you bothered to look at the docs for NSFileManager?

Comment: You are getting `NULL` from what? Does the file exist? Is the `NULL` from logging `content`? If so, use the `error` parameter. That's what it is for. To tell you why the method failed. Or is `path` `nil`?

Comment: BTW - Under the resources section of your project structure, is the `MyDirectory` folder blue or yellow?

Comment: Directory is in Yellow color.Its coming as path NULL. I have a folder structure like this. MyDirectory/Capitalization.html. If I just give Capitalization without the folder, the file and read and contents are listed.

Comment: If the folders are yellow then they are just logical groups in your project. When the app is built, it will all be flattened and all of those files will end up in the root of the app bundle. None of the files will be in any subdirectory. So your code needs to be `NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"Capitalization"  ofType:@"html"];`

Comment: rmaddy :- I checked the project directory, there MyDirectory is a physical directory.

Comment: It's a directory in your project but not in the built app. Go look in the .app folder of your built app. You won't find such a directory. That's what matters, the structure actually inside the built app. FYI - when you want to respond to someone, put an `@` before the username. Otherwise the person isn't notified.

Comment: @rmaddy I am sorry I am new to iPhone. Where can I find the .app folder. What I did was I dragged a folder into the project folder and copied it. Now I want to read this folder and read the files inside it. If I put the files outside the folder, it is reading... not problem, but can't read if it is inside the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use:

```
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:somePathString error:nil];
```

That will give you a list of the folders and files inside your selected directory.  If you want this to search subfolders then you are going to have to make a function that runs this code and call that function recursively.

In your code you are calling:

```
NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"Capitalization"  ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"MyDirectory"];
```

That is looking for anything called `Capitalization.html` in the folder `(BundlePath)/MyDirectory/` and any subfolders inside that.  Make sure you are using that correctly and that is the actual path you are trying to search.  If your `Capitalization.html` is added as a resource in the bundle then it will never be found because everything in bundle is in a single level (everything exists inside the bundle "folder").  If your `Capitalization.html` is inside a folder called `MyDirectory` that has been added by reference to the project then you are searching properly and it should work.

Long story short.  Files added as resources will always be found in the bundle directory.  Files (and folders) added as reference will maintain their folder structure and you can search for the folders properly.